# coping values from one dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas data frames `df1` and `df2`. `df1` has 3 rows and 3 columns and `df2` has 5 rows and 2 columns. I want to create a new column named `'close'` for `df2` like that in `df1`.
I want to copy the `df1` `'close'` column element to `df2` where the `df1` date, index and time columns are same with `df2` date, index, and time columns.

Below I show the dataframe I want to achieve (`df3`):

```
time= [datetime.time(10, 7, 59),
       datetime.time(15, 8, 59),
      datetime.time(11, 56, 59)]

date = ['7/2/2019',  '7/3/2019', '7/5/2019']
close = [55,65,75]

Date = ['7/2/2019', '7/2/2019', '7/3/2019', '7/5/2019', '7/5/2019']

Time = [datetime.time(10, 7, 59),
      datetime.time(10, 7, 59),
      datetime.time(15, 8, 59),
      datetime.time(11, 56, 59),
      datetime.time(11, 56, 59)]

Strike = [10000, 10000, 12300, 12200, 12200]


df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Time":time,"close":close},index = date)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Time":Time,"strike":Strike},index = Date)

# so i want to achieve df3 below

df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Time":Time,"strike":Strike,"close":[55,55,65,75,75]},index = Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### With you example data

Since the indexes of the two dataframes are matching, you can simply do

```
df2['close'] = df1['close']
```

and `pandas` will make exactly what you want. `df2` will have a new column, and will look exactly as your `df3`. No need to use the `'time'` column here, since the dates (index) have always the same time.

#### A more general case

But let's consider the case where you have same date (index) but different times. For example, say that the times in your `df2` are slightly different than the ones you posted:

```
Time = [datetime.time(10, 7, 59),
      datetime.time(13, 7, 59),
      datetime.time(15, 8, 59),
      datetime.time(11, 56, 59),
      datetime.time(14, 56, 59)]
```

In this case what you can do is to build, in each dataframe, new indexes considering both date and time (I don't know why you kept them separated in the first place).

Given your current setup, you can do:

```
ddf1 = df1.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df1.index.to_series() + ' ' + df1['Time'].apply(lambda x : x.strftime('%H:%m:%S'))))
ddf2 = df2.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df2.index.to_series() + ' ' + df2['Time'].apply(lambda x : x.strftime('%H:%m:%S'))))
```

and now, again:

```
ddf2['close'] = ddf1['close']
```

Now you will get some `nan` values in `ddf2['close']` since values are copied only for exact matches (date and time) and some times are different.